# How to describe the dual operator of $f$ denoted by $f^*$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a normed space. Let $B(X, \mathbb{R})$ be the set of all bounded linear functionals. Let linear functional $f\in X^*=B(X, \mathbb{R})$. How to describe the dual operator of $f$ denoted by $f^*$?

Note that $f^*: \mathbb{R}^*\to X^*$, that is for all $g\in \mathbb{R}^*=B(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R})$ and $x\in X$
$$
(fx, g)=(x, f^*g)
$$

Assume that $g(x)=cx$ for $c\in R$ **[Can we do that?]**

Then
$$
g(f(x))=cf(x)=(x, cf)
$$
Then
$$
f^*(cx)=f^*(g(x))=cf(x)
$$

But for $c=0$, it seems that we did not find what is $f^*$. For $c\neq 0$, we see that $f^*(y)=cf(y/c)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just playing around, and using realness, I would have said that, yes $f^*:\mathbb{R}^*\to X^*$, and it is the transpose. So taking you from a bounded linear functional on $\mathbb{R}$, say $g_c$, $x\mapsto cx$, for $c\in\mathbb{R}$ to a bounded linear functional on $X$. So, for $v\in X$:

$$\underbrace{f^*(g_c)}_{\in X^{*}}(v)=(g_c\circ f)(v)=g_c(f(v))=c\,f(v).$$

This definition is independent of $c\in\mathbb{R}$. $f^{*}$ is a linear map from $\mathbb{R}^*\to X^*$ and it is the same linear map whether it takes as input $g_0$, $g_1$ or $g_{42}$.

In particular, for $c=0$, we have $g_0(x)=0x=0$, that is $g_0=0$ is the zero map, the constant map $x\mapsto 0$, and in this case
$$f^*(g_0)=f^*(0)=0,$$
as we would expect of a linear map.

Comment: Wait. Here $g_c\in \mathbb{R}^*$ but not $X^*$, right?

Comment: So what is exactly of $f^*$? Do you mean $f^*(cx)=cf(x)$?

Comment: @Hermi $g_c$ is in $\mathbb{R}^*$. The dual $f^*$ does not take "$cx$" as input but a $g_c$. Then $f^*(g_c)$ is in $X^*$ so needs an input from $X$ which is $v$ in my notation.

Comment: ...given $f\in X^*$, $f^*$ is a map from $\mathbb{R}^*$ to $\mathbb{X}^*$ where $g\in \mathbb{R}^*$ is the input and the output is $(g\circ f)\in X^{*}$. Perhaps because $\mathbb{R}^*$ is such a simple object and every element is parameterised by a $c\in\mathbb{R}$ is somehow confusing you.